# Find position of a character in a string function in M query vs find DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, m

I tried to use the mid and find function in power BI as it can be done in excel. However, I get the error 'find' wasn't recognized.

After searching for a while a have a conclusion that `FIND` and `MID` function work in DAX (Excel and Power BI - but not in M query (edit custom) column). Instead of using find, in and M query we should use BIText, PositionOfAny.

Here is an example:
DAX:

```
MID([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL]), find([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL],"&"),3)
```

M query:

```
Text.Combine({Text.Start(Text.Upper([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL]), 3), " ",
    Text.Middle(Text.Upper([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL]),
    Text.PositionOfAny([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL], {"&"})+1, 3)})
```

It works so I would like to share because I haven't know the difference between DAX and m query in Power BI before, but this example helps.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are looking for, but I am just going to highlight the differences between m query and DAX.

M Query:

- M query is used to bring the data into the model
- This can be accessed using the Power Query Editor

DAX:

- DAX is used to create measures and columns after the data is pulled
- This is mainly used for summarizing the data

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

M and DAX are entirely different languages used for different purposes.

Primarily,

- M is how you get and transform your data before loading to the data model.
- DAX is for reading the data in your data model aggregating it to show in visuals.

There are plenty of things you can do with both where it isn't clear which is the better option. It can be highly case-dependent but the above is a simple guide.

In any case, I wouldn't recommend that M code for that purpose. Something like the following should be simpler and more similar to the DAX code:

```
Text.Middle([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL], Text.PositionOf([TRAFFIC_SIGNAL],"&"), 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I have to use M query (cant use DAX) because I need to join (merge) two table and need to modify some column before merge them. (they have different form for same value. For example ADH-110 and ad110), and closet time value of two system in different server and database).

Comment: I may not have been clear. I didn't say to use DAX. I gave a simplified M expression that was more similar to your provided DAX code than the M code you provided.

Comment: oh.Sorry for misunderstanding here. I mean thank you for your recommendation of the simple version for it in M query. (There are plenty of things you can do with both where it isn't clear which is the better option. => I just have one choice using M query in this situation :)